# Modify EventLogs using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-log

I need to read an entry from Windows Event Logs using the EventLog API, modify it and over-write that log entry. 
For e.g.: if I do something like this:

`log.Entries[0].Message = "Custom Message";`

Then I get an error saying

`"Error1 Property or indexer 'System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry.Message' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"`

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Kiran

Comment: The event log would lose quite a lot of value if this was possible.

Answer (score 3):

No, Event logs can not be modified. the `ReadOnly` control is because of this.

You can create new logs or clear current logged items, but you can not modify an existing logged item! this is a privacy control

Answer (score 1):

Write a Windows Event Logentry with the static EventLog Class.

Examplecode :

```
EventLog.WriteEntry( "your message", EventLogEntryType.<<yourtype>>);
```

For further information please consult the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx).